# Postgresql - Count of elements in nested JSON blob

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a Postgres statement that returns extracts/iterates over a json blob in the `value` column of a table.  I am able to get a count one level deep using the query below but I can't count any deeper.  I was using:

```
select jsonb_array_length(value -> 'team') as team_count
```

This returns the proper count but I cant seem to leverage this to count the `names` under each team.

In a perfect world I would my results to return 4 lines of results like this(title and a matching count of names):

```
Product Owner, 2
Technical Product Manager, 2
Data Modeler, 0 
Engineer, 0
```

How would I go about amending this query to give me the count of `names` under `team`?  I tried all sorts of stuff but nothing that got me close.

Sample Json is below.

```
"team":[
  {
     "title":"Product Owner",
     "names":[
         "John Smith",
         "Jane Doe"
     ]
  },
  {
     "title":"Technical Project Manager",
     "names":[
         "Fred Flintstone",
         "Barney Rubble"
     ]
  },
  {
     "title":"Data Modeler"
  },
  {
     "title":"Engineer"
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "title elements under team" . Are you maybe looking for  `jsonb_array_length(value -> 'team')`? That count's the number of elements in the "team" array (regardless if the objects inside that array have a key named `title`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I edited my question to add more clarity, trying your suggestion now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - this might be it... looking at this further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
SELECT
   role -> 'title' AS team_role,
   jsonb_array_length(role -> 'names') AS member_count
FROM jsonb_array_elements(value -> 'team') AS team(role)
```

Comment: this was it..  Since we came from a database I made the from 'FROM TABLE, jsonb_array_elements(value -> 'team') AS team(role).  that seems to get it done